# Replace values in multiple columns using 'numpy.where' function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to change the NA values in multiple columns when certain condition is met. Example data set given below.

```
    Pool Area   Pool Quality    Pool Type   Pool Condition  Pool Finish
0   800             Good           A              Good        Gunite
1   400             Good           C              Good        Vinyl
2   485             Good           B              Good        Fibreglass
3   360             Poor           C              Poor        Vinyl
4   0               NaN            NaN            NaN         NaN
5   600             Best           A              Best        Gunite
6   500             Best           B              Best        Fibreglass
7   0               NaN            NaN            NaN         NaN
8   750             Best           A              Best        Gunite
9   900             Best           A              Best        Gunite
10  0               NaN            NaN            NaN         NaN
11  900             Best           A              Best        Gunite
12  400             Poor           C              Poor        Fibreglass
13  0               NaN            NaN            NaN         NaN
```

In the above data, I want to replace the NaN values with 'No Pool' where the 'Pool Area' column has value '0'.

I know I can do it with **np.where** function and I tried the below code.

`df[['Pool Quality', 'Pool Type', 'Pool Condition', 'Pool Finish']] = np.where(df['Pool Area']==0, 'No Pool', df[['Pool Quality', 'Pool Type', 'Pool Condition', 'Pool Finish']])`

It isn't working.

I tried it separately, it works (Ref to code below).

`df['Pool Quality'] = np.where(df['Pool Area']==0, 'No Pool', df['Pool Quality'])`

But when I tried to do for multiple columns in one go, it is not working.

Below is the error I got.

**ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2919,) () (2919,5)**

> NOTE: The above error message is taken from my actual data set where the dimension is 2919 rows and 81 columns.

I don't know what is wrong in my code. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean indexing:

```
m = df['Pool Area'].eq(0)

df.loc[m] = df.loc[m].fillna('No Pool')
# or
# df[m] = df[m].fillna('No Pool')

# or to limit to given columns
# cols = ['Pool Quality', 'Pool Type', 'Pool Condition', 'Pool Finish']
# df.loc[m, cols] = df.loc[m, cols].fillna('No Pool')
```

updated `df`:

```
    Pool Area Pool Quality Pool Type Pool Condition Pool Finish
0         800         Good         A           Good      Gunite
1         400         Good         C           Good       Vinyl
2         485         Good         B           Good  Fibreglass
3         360         Poor         C           Poor       Vinyl
4           0      No Pool   No Pool        No Pool     No Pool
5         600         Best         A           Best      Gunite
6         500         Best         B           Best  Fibreglass
7           0      No Pool   No Pool        No Pool     No Pool
8         750         Best         A           Best      Gunite
9         900         Best         A           Best      Gunite
10          0      No Pool   No Pool        No Pool     No Pool
11        900         Best         A           Best      Gunite
12        400         Poor         C           Poor  Fibreglass
13          0      No Pool   No Pool        No Pool     No Pool
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway.  I want to understand why the first method was not working. Is there anything that you can share with me?

Comment: @Manikandan it would work for one column at a time. `numpy.where` expects the same shape in the conditional (`(14,)` in your case) and the replacement `(14, 4)`. Try with `np.where(np.tile(df[['Pool Area']]==0, (1, 4)), 'No Pool', df[['Pool Quality', 'Pool Type', 'Pool Condition', 'Pool Finish']])`